# Output a variable list of values from a function

Tags: python

I have a function that returns a variable list of values and I know you can do this by using a tuple. To assign these variables you can then do something like `a, b = func(..)`. However, if there is only one value returned you have to do `a, = func(..)` [notice the ,] rather than `a = func(..)`. To achieve the latter you can include a test to see if there is one value to be returned or more (see example below) but I wonder if there is no easier or less verbose way to do this.

```
def foo(*args):
    returnvalues = []
    for arg in args:
        arg += 100
        returnvalues.append(arg)

    if len(returnvalues) == 1:
        return returnvalues[0]
    else:
        return tuple(returnvalues)

def baz(*args):
    returnvalues = []
    for arg in args:
        arg += 100
        returnvalues.append(arg)

    return tuple(returnvalues)


a = foo(10)
b, c = foo(20, 30)
print(f'a={a}, b={b}, c={c}')

a, = baz(10)
b, c = baz(20, 30)
print(f'a={a}, b={b}, c={c}')

#
a=110, b=120, c=130
a=110, b=120, c=130
```

Comment: If you have a list of unknown length, then it makes little sense to assign that to individual variables in the first place, no?

Comment: Have a look at this [Software Engineering Question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139582/which-style-to-use-for-unused-return-parameters-in-a-python-function-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referring to "tuple unpacking". Also known as destructive assignment. The word "tuple" is a bit of a misnomer as you can use any iterable / iterator. So returning a list is fine.

```
def f():
    return [1]

(a,) = f() 
b, = f()
```

You can also use list syntax on the left hand side. There's no difference to the byte code that is generated. It does make unpacking a single item look less like a syntax error in the case of `b` and slightly less verbose than `a`.

```
[c] = f()
```

I would avoid returning the value itself and not a list in the special case where only one argument is passed. The reason for this is it makes the code harder to be used in a generic manner. Any caller of the function needs to know how many arguments it's passing or check the return value (which is clumsy). For example:

```
result = f()
if isinstance(result, (list, tuple)):
    smallest = min(result) 
else:
    smallest = result

# as opposed to this when you always return a list / tuple 
smallest = min(f())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the returning value of such a function to a single variable, so that you can use it as a list or tuple:

```
a = baz(10, 20, 30)
print(', '.join(map(str, a))) # this outputs 110, 120, 130
```